# How to turn display on and off on Windows IoT?

Tags: hdmi, windows-iot, power-management

I've got a Windows IoT UWP app wherein a motion detector will turn the display on if someone is in proximity, and then turn off after a period of no motion detected. The LCD in question is [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00U21UA16).

There are many examples of how to turn an Hdmi display on and off with Linux, but none for Windows.

The closest I've come is to turn it off with: `powercfg -change -monitor-timeout-ac 1` which sets the monitor timeout to 1 second.

Nothing I've tried, including `powercfg -change -monitor-timeout-ac 0`, turns it back on.

Is this possible on Windows IoT (code or command line)?

Comment: Did you find the answer? I am also interested in this.

Comment: Haven't found anything. Right now am looking at whether I can suspend the PI into S3 or modern standby and wake it from the PIR or wiring a bypass to the manual backlight powerswitch and controlling that from the GPIO.